# Get xhr object in vb.net while ajax calling fails

Tags: web-services, exception, jquery, error-handling, asmx

I have a big problem in `jQuery.ajax` call. I am calling the web service whenever click the update button. I have a separate web service class, in which consist of few methods. When I calling the web service method, I have made the error handling and log the error information in db after that I have to override the “ex” that means error object to `XMLHttpRequest`. Is it possible to assign the `SqlException` to ajax object (`xhr`) in `VB.NET`? Please help me its much more useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible! I try to describe it in VB.NET (mostly I use C#, but I hope I'll not made syntax errors). Let us we have a Web service

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethodAttribute(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
Public Function GetData(ByVal Age As Integer) As String
If Age <= 0 Then
    Throw(New ArgumentException("The parameter age must be positive."))
End If
'... some code
End Function
```

The same code in C# look like

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod (UseHttpGet=true)]
public string GetData(int age)
{
    if (age <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("The parameter age must be positive.");
    // some code
}
```

In case of negative Age input the exception `ArgumentException` will be thrown (all what I explain stay the same for another exception like `SqlException`).

Now you have a JavaScript code which use `jQuery.ajax` to call the service. Then you can expand the code to support the exception handling in the following way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "MyWebService.asmx/GetData",
    data: {age: -5},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        // use the data
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, ex) {
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        if (response.length > 11 && response.substr(0, 11) === '{"Message":' &&
            response.charAt(response.length-1) === '}') {

            var exInfo = JSON.parse(response);
            var text = "Message=" + exInfo.Message + "\r\n" +
                       "Exception: " + exInfo.ExceptionType;
                      // + exInfo.StackTrace;
            alert(text);
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
});
```

In case of exception be thrown, we receive information about error in JSON format. We deserialize it to the object having `Message`, `ExceptionType` and `StackTrace` property and then display error message like following

```
Message: The parameter age must be positive.
Exception: System.ArgumentException
```

In a real application you will probably never displayed the value of the `StackTrace` property. The most important information are in the `Message`: the text of exception and in `ExceptionType`: the name of exception (like `System.ArgumentException` or `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`).

Comment: No luck. Changing the URL did not change the error, and with your error code I just get an alert that says "error". But thanks!

Comment: @Oren A: The code in my answer here is simplified to show only error details on case of exception thrown by the web service. The error which you described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650561/calling-simple-web-service-asmx-file-from-ajax-and-jquery-using-json-parse-e has quite another nature. You have textStatus=**parseerror**. So you should first of all show `xhr.responseText` with `alert(xhr.responseText);`